# I want to allow invalid SSL certificates with AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I want to allow invalid SSL certificates.
My main code is below:

```
myClient = [[MyClient alloc] init];
[myClient getHtml:@"/path/to/the/distination.html"];
```

The MyClient class code is below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@interface MyClient : NSObject

- (void)getHtml:(NSString *)path;

@end

#define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_

@implementation MyClient

- (void)getHtml:(NSString *)path
{
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://trusted.server.net"]];
    [httpClient getPath:path parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
    }];
}

@end
```

I read below page and tried the macro but this doesn't work.

**Self Signed certificate SSL · Issue #189 · AFNetworking/AFNetworking** https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/189

Please help me...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To allow Invalid SSL Certificate with AFNetworking. Add the following line in AFURLConnectionOperation.h below #import Availability.h

```
#define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ 1
```

Comment: As of version 1.2.1, you don't need anymore to set this define. Instead you can set the 'allowsInvalidSSLCertificate' property to YES on AFHTTPRequestOperation, which is much more convenient.

Comment: If you do this, make sure you are only doing it in debug mode. If you are hitting HTTPS endpoints and you allow invalid certs you're losing a good portion of the security you're getting from SSL.

Comment: Is there any way to get allowsInvalidSSLCertificate to work with UIImageView+AFNetworking?

Comment: In the latest version of AFNetworking (I'm running 2.2.3) you now need to use AFSecurityPolicy and set it as the 'security' property on AFHTTPRequestOperation. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20815306/143979 for more info.

Comment: hello, i have add  **#define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ 1** in my project **AFURLConnectionOperation.h below #import Availability.h** file but i getting This Error in consol **Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=my Url.com, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=my Url.com}** @AvtarSingh Suchariya

Answer (score 45):

In AFNetworking 2.0, you can use the following:

```
[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager].securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
```

Comment: That helps. I added "self.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;" in AFHTTPRequestOperationManager init method.

Answer (score 24):

You can now use the allowsInvalidSSLCertificate property of the AFHTTPClient. No need to use defines in the latest versions of AFNetworking.

```
AFHTTPClient* client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:@"url"];
client.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES; //this defaults to no
```

Answer (score 12):

I am using RestKit so

```
client.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;
```

does not work. The option is not propagated to the operations created by restkit.

I am using cocoapods so any changes in the pch file or the pods project get overriden. 
The "hack" I have been using is a cocoapod post-install operation that adds the required preprocessor definition. At the end of my pod file I have added:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
  installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'Pods-AFNetworking'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)']
        config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] << '_AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_=1'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: On iOS7 and XCode 5 this did the trick for me. I'm using AFNetworking 1.3.3

Comment: This helped me as well. Good stuff.

Comment: currently objectManager.HTTPClient.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES; or something similar in RestKit works

Answer (score 8):

Note that if you are installing through CocoaPods, `#define`-ing this macro in your project will not be enough--the compiler macro must be set when compiling the static library in order for it to take effect.

Comment: "the compiler macro must be set when compiling the static library in order for it to take effect" - How do you do that?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you can do it using the manager for a POST operation.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager]; //initialize
 manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates=YES;    //allow unsigned
 manager.responseSerializer=[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];   //set up for JSOn  
 [manager POST:@"myweb.com" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     //success stuff
 }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     //error stuff
}];
```

EDIT - swift version:

```
    var securityPolicy = AFSecurityPolicy()
    securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = true;
    manager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
    manager.POST(
        "https://exmaple.com/foobar.php",
        nil,
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You should subclass the AFHttpClient,and override

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
                                                success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                                                failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure;
```

This is my code.

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, id))success failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *, NSError *))failure
{
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [super HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:urlRequest success:success failure:failure];

    [operation setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock:^BOOL(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace) {
        return YES;
    }];
    [operation setAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge) {
        if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }];
    return operation;
}
```

you use this httpclient and it can access self-unsigned web successfully.

Comment: Why do you need to subclass for this? Seems you could just add the protection space and authentication challenge blocks from anywhere, or am I missing something?

Comment: If you want to allow self-signed certs programmatically and still use AFHTTPClient, you need to do it this way.  Unfortunately there's no equivalent `setAuthenticationAgainstProtectionSpaceBlock` for AFHTTPClient.

Answer (score 4):

I extended AFHTTPSessionManager in my code. When testing against a test server, all I need is adding a single line like this:

```
mySessionManager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
**operation.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;**

Answer (score 2):

if you are using RestKit using

```
client.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;
```

won't work, instead do this:

in your project, click on RestKit.xcodeproj go to project > Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros

and add `_AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_=1`

thats finished.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://rdkw.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/afnetworking-_afnetworking_allow_invalid_ssl_certificates_/) is the best method for allowign invalid SSL certificates with AFNetworking.

> use add a _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ to
>
> project > Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros and add it to Debug
>   entry.

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 1):

if you are using RestKit using

```
client.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;
```

won't work, instead do this:

if you added rest kit manually to your project, click on RestKit.xcodeproj go to project > Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros

and add `_AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_=1`

thats finished.

Comment: currently objectManager.HTTPClient.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES; or something similar in RestKit works

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and no one of the solutions that I read works.

For me the only workaround is set the **AFSecurityPolicy** like this:

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
manager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;
```

I decided to reply although the question is old, maybe can help someone.