# Set/Unset _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ programmatically (at runtime)

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I´m using the AFNetworking library to perform my requests. Now I'm facing the problem with untrusted certificates.
I have a constants class in wich if I set the _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ all the untrusted certificates work. If I delete that constant I receive a -1202 code error("The certificate for this server is invalid....").

My problem is that I need to allow the user to decide if they'd like to accept invalid certificates.

Do I have a way to insert/delete a #define programmatically? 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a pull request for this here https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/873. I hope this can be included for the next AFNetworking release.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question. [I want to allow invalid SSL certificates with AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967220/i-want-to-allow-invalid-ssl-certificates-with-afnetworking)

It has examples for how to do it. Also if you're using CocoaPods be sure to do it in the Pods pch file.

Comment: It doesn't work because: #define _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_ 1 is "readed" by AFNetworking at compile time and not "Runtime" as my answer says.

Answer (score 0):

To circle back on Carlos's post above, my pull request made it into the AFNetworking 1.2.1, so grab bits from there :)