# RKObjectManager : Disable Certificate Validation

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit-0.20

How can I disable the certificate validation when I make request with RKObjectManager ?

Because I'm getting this error : 
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “the web service address” which could put your confidential information at risk."

Thank you !

Duplicate question :
[I want to allow invalid SSL certificates with AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967220/i-want-to-allow-invalid-ssl-certificates-with-afnetworking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply doing some tests against some server with the certificate misconfigured you can compile with the preprocessor macro `_AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_` defined, and the request will bypass the certificate check.

I do not recommend that approach for a production server. If a production server has a misconfigured SSL certificate, you should try to fix it (if you can) or inform the owners of the server to fix it.

Comment: Thank you @yonosoytu ! Yeah it's a test server. The certificate will be fixed later sure !

Answer (score 0):

if you are using RestKit using

```
client.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;
```

won't work, instead do this:

if you added rest kit manually to your project, click on RestKit.xcodeproj go to project > Build Settings > Preprocessor Macros

and add `_AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_=1`

thats finished.

Comment: But you can use `objectManager.HTTPClient.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;` instead.