# AFNetworking setimagewithurlrequest:placeholderImage always hit failure block

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am trying to set image in UICollectionViewCell, via collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:. I am using `AFNetworking` Image Category `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` method for loading image from cloud server.

The problem is that, I am always hitting failure block. When open the link in browser window, I can see the image.

Here is the sample code:

```
    __weak UICollectionViewCell *blockcell = cell;

    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ec2-75-101-163-253.compute-1.amazonaws.com/static/icons/app-excel%402x.png"];
    [cell.appImage setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"file-gray.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    blockcell.appImage.image = image;
        [blockcell setNeedsLayout];
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"fail for %@",request.URL);
    }];
```

There might be a simple/silly mistake. Can anyone help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The SSL certificate is not valid, just open the URL in a browser.

Comment: Solved it: We need to ignore SSL - just set this flag for operation requestOperation.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967220/i-want-to-allow-invalid-ssl-certificates-with-afnetworking

Comment: @code2kick actually the solution you should go for is to use a proper SSL certificate.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yes, I have confirmed with my server team, server is in development stage, they will add a valid certificate in the future. Marked a //TODO message to revert in the future.